# 'Coherent state' for particle in one-dimensional infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, coherent-states

Is there such superposition of states for particle in given infinite square well ('box') in which all expectation values correspond to classical behavior of particle in this kind of potential: time dependence of expectation value of position is saw-tooth wave, while time dependence of expectation value of momentum is square wave, as if classical particle moves with uniform velocity between potential barriers, instantaneously bouncing of the 'walls'?

Comment: not clear these would be temporally stable...